# Difference between Schur-Weyl dualities between $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ / $U(n,\mathbb{C})$ and the symmetric group

Tags: representation-theory

The standard Schur-Weyl duality usually refers to the one between the general linear group $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ and the symmetric group $S_n$ both acting on $V^{\otimes n} $. To my understanding, the variants of Schur-Weyl duality are between subgroups of the general linear group and corresponding centralizer algebras which contain $\mathbb{C} S_n$.

But in lots of quantum papers ([example link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.08628)), the standard Schur-Weyl duality was introduced as the duality between the unitary group and the symmetric group. I also found a post([link](https://harikrovi.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/schur-weyl-duality/)) saying that we can firstly prove the duality between $U(\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C}))$ and $S_n$ and then extend this to the one between $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $S_n$ as well as the one between $U(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $S_n$.

My question is:
How is it possible to replace $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$  by $U(n,\mathbb{C})$ while keeping the centralizer unchanged? Or is it just a trivial result caused by ignoring all elements that are in $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ but not in the unitary group?

My understanding of representation theory is limited and self-taught, so this question might be dumb. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explain how to do this in [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/four-flavors-of-schur-weyl-duality/). The idea is that the centralizer is unchanged if we pass from $U(n)$ to its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}(n)$, then (because we are acting on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and only considering complex-linear maps) still unchanged if we pass from $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ to its complexification $\mathfrak{u}(n) \otimes \mathbb{C} \cong \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$, then once again unchanged if we pass from $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ to its Lie group $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Hi Qiaochu, thank you so much! I did forget considering the space we are acting on...That's pretty helpful :)